# TA Funding Length in STEM Field in USA

Tags: funding, teaching-assistant

I understand that depending on the department and the school the duration of the TA funding for a Phd student can vary. However, I’m interested in learning whether it’s common for departments in STEM field to have less than two semesters of TA funding for the same student in US.

Comment: In some lab sciences I think it's unusual for students to be funded by TA for more than a few semesters, because they're instead fully funded on their advisor's grant and don't teach at all.

Comment: This varies a lot by discipline.  In mathematics departments the majority of students work as TA's throughout their graduate program.  In other science departments (especially those with few or no undergraduate service courses) students are often admitted to work as an RA on a particular project and won't be admitted without having found a match with a faculty member.  In some departments students are offered a first year TA and then expected to find an RA for year 2 and beyond.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that you will find many restrictions. It is fairly typical in many fields for students to spend a few years studying and paying for it as a TA. It is, normally, a job-like position, not a grant.

There may be some places that put a limit on it, but I doubt you would find anywhere that it was as little as two semesters. As long as you do a good job, of course, and keep up with your studies.

On the other hand, admission to a doctoral program doesn't automatically imply that you have a TA position. I is a separate transaction. But once you have the position, and perform well, it can continue.

Answer (score -1):

There are departments that admit PhD students with zero funding.  I would not recommend enrolling in them.  Practices vary greatly by field and institution.  Zero funding offers would be more common in social sciences.